# Empty div but still loads content on the front-end

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to know why this div tag is empty on the admin side but when the website loads on the front-end, there's more divs inside.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That container is the target div for the result of product-json. It's getting values as JSON, and then rendering it to that container.

Comment: Thank you @JoelHager. Hmmm, I looked into the JSON file, the other div containers aren't there... the product-form-component class and IDs aren't there too. I'd like to customize the page but I can't, I only knew HTML/CSS and a little JS.

Comment: The json file is what the *Javascript* uses to parse and show the data. I'd look into whatever scripts are loaded in that in the console under 'sources'. There should be a JS file that makes the call. It might be minified though, so it'll probably be tough to read. :/

Comment: @JoelHager, thank you.. again :) Yes, that makes sense. And yes, it is minified!! I just found the JS file. https://prnt.sc/sjbwia :|